# Get all days of a current week?

Tags: java

I need to get numbers of all days of a week (MON to SUN) based on which day is sent as a parameter.

For example,
I pass May 2 and I get an array [30,1,2,3,4,5,6] which is this week actually.
Or, I pass May 16 and I get an array [14,15,16,17,18,19,20].

I tried to use this code, but it return 7 days from today, which I do not want.

```
        //get which week of month
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.set(mYear, mMonth, Integer.parseInt(extractedDay));
        int weekOfMonth = now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

        //get all days of clicked week
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        calendar.set(mYear, mMonth, Integer.parseInt(extractedDay));

        String[] days = new String[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
```

But this is not what I need. I need to pass today's day (THU) and to get dates of this week of May - Mon, Apr 30 to Sun, May 6.

**EDIT**

I realized that I have a code which detects which week of a month it is. Is there a way to use this data and to set a date for Monday? For example, I pass May 16 and then I detect that it's 3rd week of May, and the I set the variable `firstDayOfWeek` (a new variable) to May 14.

Comment: Could you reduce the sample code to the essence? We don't need the "which week of month" code and it confused me at first glance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have first to subtract the weekday of the day you choose, in order to start from the first day of week. Try the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    String[] days = new String[7];
    int delta = -now.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 2; //add 2 if your week start on monday
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, delta );
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        days[i] = format.format(now.getTime());
        now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(days));

}
```

Today, it output:

[04/30/2012, 05/01/2012, 05/02/2012, 05/03/2012, 05/04/2012, 05/05/2012, 05/06/2012]

Comment: I've just tryed other days of this week. It output same results. What date are you trying?

Comment: 16 May. I try via `now.set(2012, 4, 16)` or any day other than Thu

Comment: I get this output:[05/14/2012, 05/15/2012, 05/16/2012, 05/17/2012, 05/18/2012, 05/19/2012, 05/20/2012] If I correctly understood your question, it is correct. Your output is different?

Comment: Hm, my code is slightly different. But its core is yours. Let me see which part is making a mistake. Will get back...

Comment: I added additional lines and messed up you code. Your code like this works fine. Except that it does not generate the right week when I select Sunday, but I do not care for that as Sunday will never be passed as a parameter.

Comment: today is sunday, and it skipped current date and start from tomorrow

Answer (score 7):

Your question has already been answered, but I'd like to add a bit. Your code is problematic in two ways:

1. It uses various data types for the initial date (`mYear` is `int` and `exactDay` is `String`?).
2. It mixes parsing, formatting and generation of the result.

That makes it hard for you to test the code!

Therefore, I propose a different approach:

```java
public class DaysOfCurrentWeek {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date refDate = new Date();

        Date[] days = getDaysOfWeek(refDate, Calendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek());

        for (Date day : days) {
            System.out.println(day);
        }
    }

    private static Date[] getDaysOfWeek(Date refDate, int firstDayOfWeek) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(refDate);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, firstDayOfWeek);
        Date[] daysOfWeek = new Date[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            daysOfWeek[i] = calendar.getTime();
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        return daysOfWeek;
    }
}
```

The code works like this:

1. Create a reference date (in this example just by using `new Date()`).
2. Call `getDaysOfWeek()` to do the "dirty job". By passing `firstDayOfWeek` you are free to choose `MONDAY` or `SUNDAY` as start of the week. In this example, I just use the default of the calendar.
3. Return the result - unformatted, and as `Date`. This way you can let the calling code decide what to do - print it or do some further calculations.

Now you can simply test the getDaysOfWeek() method without worrying about formatting or how the reference date has been created.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use this line of code somewhere in you current code:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
```

it should be at least before the for-loop.

Comment: I did. Still the same result. 7 days ahead from the passed day.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the day **after** you set the date

`calendar.set(mYear, mMonth, Integer.parseInt(extractedDay));`
`calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);`